# Commerce - Require login only for specific products

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm building a commerce site using drupal commerce. I know how to have anonymous users checkout, I know how to require login before checkout, but I can't figure out how to specify for each product if it requires a login or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Rules to enforce login when the product is added to the cart.

e.g

- Event: Before/After adding product to cart
- Conditions: if user is not logged in (i.e. uid=0) and product match (e.g SKU matches)
- Action: Redirect to user/login?destination=cart

Something like that could suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some special field to flag this. After you can use rules to force some users to log in.